# How to delete a bootstrap card on button click?

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-4

I am new `bootstrap` & `flask`.

I am getting response from flask api of 20 rows & displaying using bootstrap card like this -

```
<div class="row">
    {% for item in data %}

    <div class="card" style="width: 25rem;">
        {% if item[6] == '' or item[6] == ' ' %}
        <img src='static/pic_not_avl.png' class="card-img-top" alt="pic"><i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i></img>
        {% else %}
        <img src='static/{{item[6]}}' class="card-img-top" alt="pic"><i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i></img>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-center">{{item[0]}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text text-center">{{item[7]}}</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>State : </strong>{{item[1]}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Salary : </strong>{{item[2]}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Grade : </strong>{{item[3]}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Room : </strong>{{item[4]}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Telnum : </strong>{{item[5]}}</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#updateModal">Update</button>
            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button> -->
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/deleteDatail?dname={{item[0]}}" role="button">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Now i want to delete a card (one data) on button click.

tried like this -

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/deleteDatail?dname={{item[0]}}" role="button">Delete</a>
```

But I am getting error `Method not allowed`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: you should add your flask code to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/deleteDatail?dname={{item[0]}}` implies a GET call to your flask route. The error `Method not allowed` means your route does not support a `GET`. You have to do something like

```
   @app.route("/deleteDetail/")
   def deleteDetail():
        dname = request.values.get("dname", None)
```

or you can do

```
@app.route("/deleteDetail/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
   def deleteDetail():
        if request.method == 'POST':
          dname = request.values.get("dname", None)
```